# Embed Icon in WPF application

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf-controls, icons, notifyicon

I am using an icon in my application in two situations.

1. In XAML as an Image for the Button using DynamicResource.
2. In C# as NotifyIcon

   this.notifyIcon.Icon = new SystemDrawing.Icon("..//..//Shutdown.ico" );

My problem is if I delete the image the application not working. How can I bind the image with the exe file so that the application can run only with the exe file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the icon to the project as a Resource (not Embedded Resource, there is a difference), then access it with

```
using (var stream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Shutdown.ico")).Stream)
{
    this.notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(stream);
}
```

You should also then be able to use it in your XAML too, I just can't remember how yet.

See here for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/wpf-application-resource-content-and-data-files

*Note*: I have not included any error checking here. You should probably make sure you check the stream to see if it is null before using it.

Comment: When I use I got an error
Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Resources.StreamResourceInfo' to 'System.IO.Stream'

Comment: I missed the .Stream call on the end of the GetResourceStream() call. Did you look at StreamResourceInfo to see where I went wrong? You aren't going to get anywhere just copy pasting code without figuring out how it works.

Answer (score -1):

The last time I needed to do this, the image was so simple that it was easiest to simply create a line drawing in XAML (similar to SVG) instead of using a file. I was attempting to build a simple Vista-style wizard without reusing anyone else's code (to see if I could), and I wanted the arrow of a command button as can be seen in the [UX guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511482.aspx) on MSDN.