# How do I load an icon using GetResourceStream in WPF?

Tags: wpf, resources, uri

I've added an icon to my WPF project (BuildAction set to Resource) and I'm now trying to load that icon into a stream:

```
using(Stream iconStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("red.ico")).Stream)
{
    // use the stream
}
```

This gives me the following error:

> Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

I've tried altering the Uri construction to include UriKind.Relative.  This gives:

> Cannot locate resource 'red.ico'.

I've looked at various articles on this [For Example (from SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985003/embed-icon-in-wpf-application) and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately my issue boiled down to the fact that I had created a custom entry point for my WPF application and I was attempting to create a URI before the Application's static constructions had been called.

The code changed from something like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var myUri = new Uri("/red.ico", UriKind.Relative);

    var app = new AppMain();
    app.Run();
}
```

to something like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var app = new AppMain();        

    var myUri = new Uri("/red.ico", UriKind.Relative);

    app.Run();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like `new Uri("pack://application:,,,/red.ico")`, see [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more info on URIs in WPF.

Comment: I've tried that too :-)  It results in a FormatException with the message "Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.".  I'll take a look at the link you posted.  Thanks.

Comment: @Micky: If you get "This topic is no longer available" just select the latest (available) version from the 'other versions' dropdown. It's dumb behavior, the website should really do that on its own since the url does not specify a .NET version.